Web3 JS (MetaMask Ext and Metamask Mobile)
So i’m having a trouble here. I’m calling my contract function on web3 js, it’s currently on local hosted and i’m using react js.
When it comes to calling contract, it seems working fine when i’m using metamask extension on google.
But it does not work on metamask mobile.
I’m accessing my local react app using local ip address in the same wifi connection.
Please, can someone tell me about this? Or is this just a normal security reason?

What's the code you are using? Did you use a framework like etherjs, wagmi, etc? Usually browsers handle localhost with care for security reasons.
